# Is there a benefit for accessing fields via `this`?

Tags: java, coding-style

I am looking at a very old code-base, and *every* field access follows this pattern:

```
void method() {
  TYPE fieldRef = this.field;
  // Use fieldRef instead of field
}
```

I can't figure out why this pattern is followed rigorously. Is there some performance benefit to this? Does it have something to do with how fields behave with inheritance?

Comment: Is there some multi-threading going on?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, there is multi-threading. And I can see how following this style of code could reduce inconsistencies. I will check the code once again, to see if that's why they are doing it this way.

Comment: @user1803551 That other question is a little different. I know when I should use this. But in this code-base, *every* field access is using `this`.

Comment: I found a more relevant duplicate. Since I can't delete this question, I am voting my own question be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`this` always refers the current class variables in the scenario you mentioned

so the benefit is just that the purpose of assigning value is satisfied the way it should be

> Is there some performance benefit to this?

No its not for performance improvement

> Does it have something to do with how fields behave with inheritance?

only if your parent class variables have same names Yes, or it does not have any thing to do with Inheritance as well

EDIT:

```
// Use fieldRef instead of field
```

this we usually do because in java if your field is an `Object`, it maintains reference and any modifications we do gets reflected in original object property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the coder wants to catch the instance object that `this.field` refers to with a temporary reference and immediately assign a different instance object to `this.field`.